# Java Web Project referencing another Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have a `Java Project`, for which I'm now creating a Web interface, using a `Dynamic Web Project` from Eclipse. The Web project consists of a single `servlet` and two `JSP`'s. Something like this:

```
/JavaApplication
  /src
  /lib
  /resources
/WebApplication
  /src
    /Servlet.java
  /WebContent
    /WEB-INF
    index.jsp
    other.jsp
```

Now, I need to reference `JavaApplication` from `WebApplication`, in order to use its classes to process web requests. What's the best way to accomplish this ? My idea is to create a `.jar` of the `JavaApplication`, containing all the `.class` files, `/resources`, and `/libs`. In this way, I could include the .jar in the web application, and I could have a single `.war` file that contained the entire application.

What do you think? How is this problem typically solved ?

Note: I don't want to convert the Java Project into a Web project.

Comment: I had the same issue. An answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693322/eclipse-web-project-dependencies solved it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under Eclipse, you can declare *Project References* for a given project, the web application in your case. To do so, right click on your web application project, then go for *Properties > Project References* and select the `JavaApplication` project. This should allow you to call code from the `JavaApplication` project from the `WebApplication` without having to build a WAR. This is a solution for **development**.

For standard **deployment** (outside the IDE), you should indeed create a standard WAR. To do so, you'll have to package your `JavaApplication` as a JAR including the `.class` files and the files under `/resources` but **not** the libraries it depends on (JARs under `/lib`). These dependencies will actually end up in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the WAR, beside the JAR of your `JavaApplication`. These steps are typically automated with tools like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: Yes, I'm using that solution for development. As for deployment, that's what I'm probably going to do, after researching a bit the .EAR files. Thanks.

Comment: Did this suggestion work, I am trying it, but keep getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at runtime although everything compiles correctly in my servlets.

Answer (score 16):

In Eclipse project properties, add the project to the *Java EE Module Dependencies* (Eclipse 3.5 or older)

[image: Java EE Module Dependencies]

or *Deployment Assembly* (Eclipse 3.6 or newer) entry in the project properties.

[image: Deployment Assembly]

This way Eclipse will take care about doing the right thing to create a WAR out of this all (it will end in `/WEB-INF/lib`). No other configuration is necessary, even not some fiddling in *Build Path*.

Comment: Just a quick note: for Eclipse 3.6 and up, "Java EE Module Dependencies" is renamed to "Deployment Assembly"

Comment: I've been searching for hours on this. This worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Connecting java app to web app for development :

right click on web project :

> properties>project references> add the java project you want to refer

Now in properties tab of web project go to

> properties>deployment assembly> add the project manually  and run the app

Answer (score 2):

Consider moving up to EAR level, if your web container supports that.

The tricky part with shared code is where should the common code be put.  A copy pr web application?  A copy in the web container?   Overdoing the "share these classes" might end  up in class loader problems.

If you are creating two *separate* web applications refactor common java code into a separate Eclipse project and refer to it from both WAR projects.

---

EDIT:  Apparently I have misread the problem description, and thought you asked about an existing and a new web application sharing code.

If you have an Eclipse project with your application, and another with your web frontend, then you can let your application export the necessary resources which the "Export WAR" in Eclipse Java EE can wrap up in a jar file and put in WEB-INF/lib for you.  You need to say this explicitly with a checkmark in  Properties -> Java EE Module Dependencies for your web project.  Expect you have to experiment a bit - this took me a while to learn.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the EAR solution. With respect to shared code, there isn't any. The web application is a simple front-end to the java application, which makes use of an `Engine` to process requests and feed some simple beans to the JSPs. Since this interface is for demonstration purposes, it needs to be easily deployed (I'm currently using `jetty-runner`). For development, I'm using the solution @Pascal described, but I'm still looking for a better solution for deployment (currently, I'm passing everything I need [libs, resources, .classes] to `jetty-runner`).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would create an API interface using remote service beans from the Java application that expose the methods that you want to invoke in the web application. You would include a proxy of the API interface with your web application that calls the remote service bean in the Java application. Remember that you will need to register the remote bean in the web.xml file.

Comment: JG wants to use classes from his applications which may be a simple execuatble jar, I'm not sure using remote service beans would help. I guess his solution is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's a little over-the-top for my current needs.