# Can't deploy correctly required project with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment

I'm developing a web-application on Eclipse.
I've implemented the DAL as a separate project and set it as dependency of my main project.

I can compile the main project, but when I run it, i get this exception:

`SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet InputServlet threw exception

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

It can't find a class that is in my **"DAL Project"** so it seems that classes of this project are not deployed in Tomcat when I run the web-app.

How can I solve it? Is there something to configure?

Comment: Did you add it as a dependency correctly? Try adding that project to the build path.

Comment: @Jeremy yes, I added the DAL Project to the build path, in fact i can use objects packaged in this project in my main project (web-app), and i get no compile-time errors. But when I run the main project the `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem following the answer of **rodgarcialima** to this question: [Eclipse Web Project Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1693322/1061499):

> 1. Go to web project properties.
> 2. Deployment Assembly (Left).
> 3. Add > Select project > Select your lib project > Check "Assemble projects into the WEB-INF/lib folder of the web application" if not checked > Finish.
> 4. Java Build Path (Left) > Projects Tab > Add... > Select your lib project > OK
> 5. Java Build Path (Left) > Order and Export Tab > Select your lib project.
> 6. Save
> 7. Now it works.