# javax.servlet.http.HTTPServlet Import cannot be resolved while the rest of the package imports fine

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, import

I am working on [a tutorial](https://eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html) to learn how to build a basic web app on eclipse, run locally on tomcat. However I can't seem to access the HTTPServlet class, while it appears that I can still import other javax.servlet.http files.

```
package org.eclipse.wtp.tutorial;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HTTPServlet; //This import has an error, "Cannot be resolved"
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SnoopServlet extends HTTPServlet {}
```

I have gone through these stack overflow answers with no changes to my situation:
[Importing servlet API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project?lq=1)
[Adding Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756153/the-superclass-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-was-not-found-on-the-java-build)

And I wanted to try the second answer of adding a dependency to the project, but there is no pom, and [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693322/eclipse-web-project-dependencies) of adding a dependency isn't working for me (I don't have the options necessary to do #3)

What is going wrong here?

Comment: And what is the name of the class (hint - upper/lower case counts)?

Comment: Correct the name of the class `HTTPServlet` should be `HttpServlet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, class names are case sensitives. The correct name is `HttpServlet` (lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; //this is correct
import javax.servlet.http.HTTPServlet; //incorrect
```