# when running restful service org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, glassfish

I am trying to run the restful webservice in tomcat server am getting the following exception

```
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer ClassNotFoundException
```

my deployment descriptor is

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestFul application</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.web.service</param-value>
         </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestFul application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

when i refer

[org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022114/org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer-classnotfoundexception)

above url it says, when we refer 2.x libraries and add 1.x libraries to work space then this problem will come, but i have referred to 2.x libraries in web.xml descriptor and added 2.x libraries to the workspace

I have referred to screen shot below of my libraries added

am really confused why am I getting this exception

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: make sure that those dependencies are in WEB-INF/lib of your webapp once deployed on tomcat

Comment: I thought that when we create a war corresponding jar's will also get packed

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693322/eclipse-web-project-dependencies)?